# perl HTML::TableExtract out of range error

Tags: html, perl, html-tableextract

I am having difficulty recovering data from within an HTML table.
Here is what I have.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::TableExtract qw(tree); #
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $d = 3; 
my $c = 4; 

$te = HTML::TableExtract->new( depth => $d, count => $c ); # , decode => 1, gridmap => 1
$te->parse($mech->content);
print "\nDepth = $d, Count = $c \n\n";
my $table = $te->first_table_found;
my $table_tree = $table->tree();
my @rows = $table->rows();
print "The row count is   : ".$rowcount,"\n";
print "The column count is: ".$colcount,"\n";
foreach my $row (@rows)
{
   my @read_row = $table->tree->row($row);
   foreach my $read (@read_row)
   {
      print $read, "\n";
   }
}
```

I get this as the error message.

```
"Rows(ARRAY(0x2987ef8)) out of range at test4.pl line 91."
```

Is there a better way of looking through the table and getting the values. 
I have no headers to look for and I have looked at [HTML::Query](http://search.cpan.org/~kamelkev/HTML-Query/lib/HTML/Query.pm) but couldn't find it or the required [Badger::Base](http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Badger-0.05/lib/Badger/Base.pm) through PPM and [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-Element-Extended-1.18/lib/HTML/ElementTable.pm) looks like it's better used for table construction.
I'm also using [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) earlier in the script.

Any help on my code above would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need *tree extraction mode* for most purposes.

Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write, and declare your variables as close as possible to their first point of use.

Your call `$table->rows()` returns a list of *array references*, that you can access like this

```
my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(depth => $d, count => $c); # , decode => 1, gridmap => 1
$te->parse($mech->content);
printf "\nDepth = %d, Count = %d\n\n", $d, $c;

my $table = $te->first_table_found;
my @rows = $table->rows;

for my $row (@rows) {
  print join(', ', @$row), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin. In my attempt to declutter the code I forgot the modules as well as use strict and use warnings. They are there in my actual code :). I get a data element hash reference like this one for each cell with this code though HTML::ElementTable::DataElement=HASH(0x3b91ff8). Any idea how to get around that.

Comment: @MicrobicTiger: have you removed the `tree` from `HTML::TableExtract`? As I said, you don't need it here and it just makes the code more complicated. You also appear to be missing a declaration for `$te`, or at least it isn't where it should be. You should put it where it is first used as I have in my own code.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. 
I have some uninitialized values but that works much better. Thanks @Borodin, I have appreciated your help these last few days.